# Enable blur for specific window in compton

Tags: compton

Is there any way to turn off blur for ALL windows except specific ones? Another words, is there something like "blur-background-include" rules, contrasting "blur-background-exclude"? I know, it is possible to manage opacity for specific windows, but this is not what I want. I want to turn off blur for all windows, but to leave them transparent.